# Yii database connection

Tags: php, sqlite, yii

Is there any dynamic way to put sqlite database connection instead of using `sqlite:f:\\wamp\\www\\qdr\\protected\\data\\testdrive.db in main.php` ?

```
'db'=>array(
          'connectionString'=>'sqlite:f:\\wamp\\www\\qdr\\protected\\data\\testdrive.db',
),
```

Comment: i think i need to install xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql lite is about a single file so you can keep it like this. No dynamic needed. I am sure you are using wamp. Just keep it like this. This is the best solution for you. When you move the project to live server then change accordingly. Sqlite is a single file so do not bother that much.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you understand under the vague term *dynamic*. But you could for example create your custom `DBConnection` class and override `init()` there:

```
class DbConnection extends CDbConnection
{
    public function init()
    {
        // Set $this->connectionString to whatever you want, maybe
        // $this->connectionString = 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db';
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

You can use this component as `db` component if you add

```
'class' => 'DbConnection',
```

to your `main.php`.

Note, though, that the `init()` method is only called the first time when the `db` component is accessed. So whatever you set as `connectionString` there will be used for the current request.

Comment: i want to use '.dirname(__FILE__).' in the string so that this code can be used in any machine not only in my drive sqlite:f:\\wamp\\www\\qdr\\protected\\data\\testdrive.db

Comment: can you give an working example please... i am not understanding how to implement

Comment: I don't understand. The above *is* a working example. I can not make it any simpler or do your work for you. If you really can't follow that simple code i'd say that Yii is the wrong framework for you.